# Using Java RegEx to find words that start with Upper case and contain lower case

Tags: java, regex

So I am using Java Regex to find acronyms.  Most of the Acronyms I am getting are all uppercase, which is fine I have the reg ex for that what I need is a regex for words that will have one lower case letter and the rest are upper case like CCaRS.  What Regex could I use for this?  Below is a sample of the All upper case Regex I am using.

```
 String twoPlusUCRegEx = "[A-Z][A-Z]+";
```

Sample Acronyms: CCaRS, MiDAE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String regex = "\\b([A-Z])(\\S*?)\\b";
```

just have a try

Answer (score 1):

This should work (any combination of letters starting with an uppercase including 2 or more uppercase ones):

```
String twoPlusUCRegEx = "([A-Z][a-z]*){2,}";
```

Answer (score 0):

The following regex should work:

```
[A-Z]+[a-z][A-Z]*
```

Explanation:

```
[A-Z]+   # one or more uppercase characters
[a-z]    # exactly one lowercase character
[A-Z]*   # zero or more uppercase characters
```

Note that the body of your text implies that the string doesn't need to start with an uppercase character, but your title says that it does.  Please clarify whether or not starting with uppercase is a requirement.

Comment: Actually, you don't really need anchors in this case.

Comment: Good point, I don't use Java often so I had forgotten about `String.matches()`.

Comment: @Rohit anchor does really matter?

Comment: @smit.. Well, since anchors are used to match the pattern at the ends, so in this case, they are not really required, as the regex is itself built to match the complete string. Plus, if we use `String.matches` then anchors are redundant. Also, just to confirm, using them would not affect the result though.

Comment: @Rohit What do you mean by "at the end"? This is something I really dont know.

Comment: @smit. At the beginning and end of a string. E.g - `^abc$` will not match - `lkjabca`, but will only match - `abc`.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
([A-Z]+[a-z][A-Z]*)|([A-Z]*[a-z][A-Z]+)
```

If at least 1 uppercase letter is required.

If not:

```
[A-Z]*[a-z][A-Z]*
```